# Changing size of jpg plot in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, turkish

I am trying to add matplotlib plots in my LaTeX document. I saved those plots in .jpg format. I want these two plots to be half size of line width, in the same line. However when I write this code below:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 50mm]{my_plot_1.jpg}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

I get following output:
[image]

I tried both width and scale parameters, but it displayed as text. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: Try removing the space around the `=`, or look at the log to see if there's any errors.

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! If I insert your code fragment in an `aericle` document, I get expected result, i.e. image with 50 mm width.

Comment: You probably forgot `\usepackage{graphicx}` *and* ignored the "undefined command"  error.

Comment: @user202729 spaces are removed by `keyval`, that's not the issue.

Comment: I tried to remove space before and after =, also \usepackage{graphicx} but it didn't work. Width parameter still displays as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please always post a complete example document (with `\documentclass`, a short preamble and `\begin{document}...\end{document}`) and not just code snippets. Often it is next to impossible to find out the cause of the problem from just a code snippet.

Here are some guesses about your situation.

Make sure you have loaded the `graphicx` package (`\usepackage{graphicx}`).

Your screenshot suggests your document is in Turkish. `babel`'s Turkish language module makes the `=` an active character, which means that `=` can break when it is used in key-value arguments.

There are several ways to resolve the issue. One is to locally deactivate the `=` shorthand with `\shorthandoff` (and turn it on later with `\shorthandon`).

```
\documentclass[turkish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{=}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 50mm]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\shorthandon{=}
\end{document}
```

But you could also deactivate the shorthand globally by only activating the other two shorthands `:` and `!`. (If I understand correctly, the only purpose of making `=` active is to change its spacing in text mode. I assume one rarely has a `=` in text mode.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 50mm]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Image (width 50mm) with caption. No spurious text output.]

Comment: Deactivating = worked for me. Thanks for help.

Comment: +1 for a really good explanation