# Bibliography with Turkish Babel missing author name

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, babel, turkish

I am trying to prepare my bibliography, but when I try to add some references it comes without authors of references.

Here is my `main.text`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{top=30mm,right=30mm,left=30mm,bottom=30mm}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[english,turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{=!}
%\input{Chapters/Titlepage}
%\input{Chapters/Titlepage2}
%\input{Chapters/Abstract}
\input{Chapters/Micromechanics of Lamina}
\input{Chapters/MacroMechanics of Lamina}
\input{Chapters/Macromechanical Analysis of Laminates}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is my bibliography, it is just for a demo right now.

```
@article{knuth:1984,
title={Literate Programming},
author={Donald, Knuth},
journal={The Computer Journal},
volume={27},
number={2},
pages={97--111},
year={1984},
publisher={Oxford University Press}
}
```

And this is the result I get:

[image]

Comment: Hi, with the code you've provided, the document doesn't compile. Please convert this to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). This would involve removing any line that references an unnecessary external file (like the `\input{}` commands), and also any packages that are unnecessary for reproducing the problem with the bibliography. If I comment out the `\input{}` commands, I still can't get this to compile—the cause seems to be to do with the `babel` and `shorthand` lines.

Comment: For what it's worth, when I comment out the `babel` line entirely, the document compiles, *and* the author name is there. So, at least it's not missing information, just a weird interaction between commands.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. When I write the paragraph without Turkish Babel, it doesn't fit within the page boundaries and no justifies. How can I find a solution to this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know. I don't have experience with `babel`, or LaTeX in Turkish. I just thought I would include those details here in case they help someone else hone in on the problem. I would suggest maybe putting `babel` or Turkish into the question title, since that is part of the problem. That might help attract people who have a better idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here are `babel-turkish`'s shorthand settings. `babel-turkish` makes `=` active, which brakes many key-value packages. Since `biblatex` uses key-value syntax for names, those error and will not show.

In the example the problematic shorthands for `!=` are disabled after `\begin{document}`, but that is slightly too late for `biblatex`, as it reads the `.bbl` file (which contains all the bibliographic data, amongst them names) at `\begin{document}`.

With the new hook management system we can fine-tune the placement of `\shorthandoff` within `\begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\AtBeginDocument[biblatex/shorthands]{%
  \shorthandoff{=!}%
}

\DeclareHookRule{begindocument}{biblatex/shorthands}{before}{biblatex}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson ve Ryde 1998)]

Another way to resolve this problem would be to use the `shorthands` option to explicitly enable those shorthands that we want. Turkish sets `:`, `=` and `!`. If we disable `!=` we're left with `:`, so we say `shorthands=:`. If you don't even want an active colon, go with `shorthands=off`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, turkish, shorthands=:]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160385/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/627908/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/637450/35864.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I found your second solution in babel documentation. It works very well. Thanks :).